# NPM error when trying to install gulp and bower

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp, bower

I'm trying to install gulp and bower by running `npm install --global gulp bower` . Everything seems to be going fine then I get this:

```
npm ERR! Darwin 15.0.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "--global" "yo" "gulp" "bower"
npm ERR! node v4.2.2
npm ERR! npm  v3.5.0
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/vinyl-fs/node_modules/glob-stream/node_modules/ordered-read-streams
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! syscall rename

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/vinyl-fs/node_modules/glob-stream/node_modules/ordered-read-streams' -> '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/ordered-read-streams'
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/vinyl-fs/node_modules/glob-stream/node_modules/ordered-read-streams' -> '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/ordered-read-streams'
npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/deang/npm-debug.log
```

I've also tried running the command using `sudo`, but to no avail. Any pointers?

**Update:**

This seems to be happening for everything I'm trying to install. Just tried `sudo npm install --global generator-gulp-webapp` and it did the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you using npm 3.x? if so, try downgrading to npm 2.x (you can `npm install npm@2.14.12`).

npm 3.x has [a couple of issues](https://github.com/yeoman/yeoman/issues/1488) with yeoman